# How to get current value of useState in useEffect without re-running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect, use-state

I need to initiate a function only once, which fires WebSocket events whenever new objects are created on backend.

I try to store these added objects in a state array using `useState`.

But every time a new object is created, the last added values are not found, it is always a fresh array. How can I get the current value of the state `notifs` without running the function again every time it is changed?

```
    const [notifs, setNotifs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        const subscribe = () => {
            //Socket subscription : When new object is created
            let subs = new SocketSubscription();
            subs('create', (object) => {
                let newNot = Notification.initFromPFObject(object)
                alert("Notification : " + newNot.message)

                //PROBLEM: NOTIFS here are always a blank array [] 
                let ntt = [...notifs]
                ntt.unshift(newNot)
                setNotifs(ntt)
            });
        }

        subscribe()

    }, [])
```

Comment: You can try `setNotifs((curr) => [newNot, ...curr]);`

Comment: Works.. i didn't think it was this simple :) ... Please answer.. so i can accept it @DecPK

Comment: Another option if things get more complex and you need access to notifs more than just inside the setter callback, is you could use refs, `useRef` etc..

Comment: @Keith Could you show an example with code. Keep it simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing new value to `setNotifs` you can pass a function which receives `currentValue` as first parameter and you can update it as:

```
setNotifs((curr) => [newNot, ...curr]);
```

> AFAIT the main reason is that you are close over `notifs` which has `[]` array. When then callback to `subs` called then it takes the stale value not the current value. So you can pass function to `setNotifs` which automatically recieves `current` value as first pararmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
setNotifs(prevNotifs => [newNot, ...prevNotifs])
```